# What is the reason behind Pinterests use of bit-manipulation to create global IDs for sharding of their data on MySQL, and how does it work?

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation

I am reading an article on how Pinterest managed to scale with MySQL, by sharding their data across multiple servers and databases within those servers.

The one part I am struggling with is how they create their global ID with bit-manipulation.

I understand how operators like & and | works. And I understand how left shift << and right shift >> work. But I don't understand how they all work together in this example.

From the article it says:

https://medium.com/@Pinterest_Engineering/sharding-pinterest-how-we-scaled-our-mysql-fleet-3f341e96ca6f

> We created a 64 bit ID that contains the shard ID, the type of the
>   containing data, and where this data is in the table (local ID). The
>   shard ID is 16 bits, type ID is 10 bits and local ID is 36 bits. The
>   savvy additionology experts out there will notice that only adds to 62
>   bits. My past in compiler and chip design has taught me that reserve
>   bits are worth their weight in gold. So we have two (set to zero).

So the shard ID is 16 bit, max 65536 - 1, type ID is 10 bit, max value 1024 - 1, and local ID is 36 bit, max value 68719476736 - 1.

What does he mean by the last statement?

> My past in compiler and chip design has taught me that reserve bits
>   are worth their weight in gold. So we have two (set to zero).

Next line shows us a way to get a 64 bit ID:

```
ID = (shard ID << 46) | (type ID << 36) | (local ID<<0)
```

I am struggling to understand this. Why is the shard ID left shifted by 46? And why is the type ID left shifted by 36 and why is the local ID left shifted by 0, and why do we have an OR between all of these?

Next part is they where they are extracting the local ID, type ID and local ID from a global ID of 241294492511762325:

```
Shard ID = (241294492511762325 >> 46) & 0xFFFF = 3429
Type ID  = (241294492511762325 >> 36) & 0x3FF = 1
Local ID = (241294492511762325 >>  0) & 0xFFFFFFFFF = 7075733
```

So here they do the opposite, they shift to the right, the same amount as the original left shift, I don't know why exactly shifting by those amounts but I can see the pattern. But now they are doing & with some hexadecimal numbers, and this I also do not understand.

I am trying to learn how to shard data manually in MySQL, and would be nice if I could understand the logic of why they are doing it like this, and how it works. I do understand how simple & and | and << and >> operators work, I learned it by reading this article:

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301

But I don't understand how it all works together, and I don't understand why they use those shifting numbers, and why they do & with hexadecimal numbers at the end.

Would be awesome if I could understand this.

Comment: If I can't ask this on Stack Overflow, then where should I ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Next line shows us a way to get a 64 bit ID:
>
> ```
> ID = (shard ID << 46) | (type ID << 36) | (local ID<<0)
> ```
>
> I am struggling to understand this. Why is the shard ID left shifted by 46? And why is the type ID left shifted by 36 and why is the local ID left shifted by 0, and why do we have an OR between all of these?

So to reiterate:

- local ID: 36 bits
- type ID: 10 bits
- shard ID: 16 bits

The full ID contains the IDs in order "shard, type, local". Since, local ID has 36 bits, you have to shift type ID by 36 bits. Type ID has 10 bits, so you have to shift type ID by an additional 10 bits (36 bits from local ID + 10 bits from type ID).

A bitwise OR (`|`) will set all the bits to 1 which are set to 1 in at least one of the operands.

For instance:

```
shard ID = 0b                         1011_1100_1001_0010
type ID  = 0b                                11_1010_0110
local ID = 0b1010_0100_1111_1101_1110_0011_1000_0000_0111
```

if you shift those values by the specified bits, that gives you:

```
shard ID << 46 = 0b10_1111_0010_0100_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000
type ID  << 36 = 0b                    11_1010_0110_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000
local ID <<  0 = 0b                                 1010_0100_1111_1101_1110_0011_1000_0000_0111
```

and if you OR that, you get the result:

```
  0b10_1111_0010_0100_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000
| 0b                    11_1010_0110_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000
| 0b                                 1010_0100_1111_1101_1110_0011_1000_0000_0111
= 0b10_1111_0010_0100_1011_1010_0110_1010_0100_1111_1101_1110_0011_1000_0000_0111
```

---

To extract the IDs again, you have to apply bit masks with the bitwise AND (`&`) operator. It is the opposite of the OR operator: it will only set bits to 1 when both operands have that bit set. So to take your example:

> Type ID  = (241294492511762325 >> 36) & 0x3FF = 1

Let's convert to binary first, so that dependencies of the operators and their operands become clear:

```
0b11_0101_1001_0100_0000_0001_0000_0000_0000_0110_1011_1111_0111_1001_0101
```

Right shift by 36 bits:

```
0b                                             11_0101_1001_0100_0000_0001
```

Apply bit mask (0x3FF = 0b11_1111_1111) of 10 bits:

```
  0b11_0101_1001_0100_0000_0001
& 0b               11_1111_1111
= 0b               00_0000_0001
```

Which, in decimal notation, is also 1.

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand the OR part too. Thank you so much! But what about the second part where they do & with hexadecimal numbers? I don't understand that part.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand everything now, I also understand why they use bit operations to concatenate numbers to keep its uniqueness since you can't just add them together or concatenate like you do with strings since that too might collide with another result. Thanks!